# Boost Test output in xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode4, boost-test

I am trying Boost.Test for the first time in Xcode 4. I could get the tests given in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/example/unit_test_example_01.cpp) example running well. Of course, I had to add **#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK** in addition to what's given in the example. However, the output in the xcode console (debug area) looks scrambled as

```
Running 2 test cases...
/Users/nikhil/Desktop/work-temp/sampleApp/sampleApp/main.cpp:32: error in "> ���
\356\277_\377��\274R�����\241\355\277_\377��
\356\277_\377��\274R�����\301R�����0\356\277_\377��@\356\277_\377��\256�����\270\270\303_\377����������\356\277_\377��\367
2\216\377": check 
*** 2 failures detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
```

I am sure it is something to do with the log_formatter, but could not guess what/how. Can someone help me please?

**EDIT**

The problem apparently is due to compiler incompatibilities (an information never provided here). Refer to my answer below.

TIA,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have a concrete answer on this issue for now, though I got my stuff working and for the benefit of those who have been or might come across the same issue:

The **Boost.Test** library after version 1.50 (I am using 1.53 currently) does not support pre- gcc4.4 compilers. Current clang utilizes gcc4.2 and that causes most of the trouble (also the above).

In that sense, my problem was not where I was looking at, but in the project compilation configuration!

Nikhil